# Ubuntu 16.04 -- RubyonRails install will not complete successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Went to the RubyOnRails.org site to install and set up RubyOnRails. Ruby language installed just fine. Followed the instruction at RoR to the letter. Unfortunately, the install would not complete and RubyOnRails could not be used. The error messages (see below) yielded no specific clues as to how to correct them. Any advice would be very appreciated.

The Ruby on Rails 'Getting Started' tutorial has fatal errors.

```
'gem install rails' fails: extconf.rb and missing libraries (zlib1g-dev and nodejs).
'rails new blog' fails: bundle and bundler fail.
'bin/rails server' fails: uglifier could not load.
```

So, no web server, no Rails.
I am Using Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit. Standard fresh installation. Much digging and searching the web took HOURS to finally discover all the errors. Ruby on Rails 5.0.0.1 normal install.

Comment: Some question regarding your issue. 1. Are you using windows operating system? 2. Did you installed `nodejs` in your machine?

Comment: Required components seem to be missing... "missing libraries", "could not load".